# Table form element

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

Is there a way in the Form API to have a form element display in a table (think like a list of fees) where one of the rows value could be changed with AJAX from another form element?

For example, if the default 'Subscription fee' is $10, and I select a different 'Subscription Plan' method, when I click the option, how do I change that fee row to $20 or whatever the amount may be?

I am trying to utilize the #ajax framework as much as possible with the Form API but I am not seeing how this is easily achievable.

The way I have rendered the form is to assemble the header and rows, then output a form Item element with theme('table') as its #markup, but I am getting an HTML string instead of an actual data array to manipulate (which is its intent, but I need something to manipulate with JS/PHP).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this blog entry that reproduces exactly (what it sounds like) you are trying to do: http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/make-link-use-ajax-drupal-7-its-easy

If you post your code it would be easier to troubleshoot.

You might also want to take a look at the code from the ajax_example module in the [examples](http://dgo.to/examples) module.

Comment: Not really, I'd need a radio button or checkbox to (when clicked) change one or more values in a table within the form. I've been stuck on this for a while. I haven't seen a more advanced Drupal FAPI ajax example to shed some light on this.

Comment: You are right that the example blog post uses a link to fire the ajax callback, but using [#ajax] should work with a radio button http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax If you've got some generic code I'd be happy to give it a try